# How to dynamically transpose a single Column to multiple Rows in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pivot, transpose

I have a dataframe that looks like below

| ColName |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| c |
| d |
| e |
| f |
| g |
| h |
| i |
| j |
| k |
| l |

and based on an specific parameter I want to transpose those values into rows. So for example if the parameter value is 3, the new dataframe will look like below

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |
| g | h | i |
| j | k | l |

However if the parameter value is 4, it will look like below

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d |
| e | f | g | h |
| i | j | k | l |

A few things to notice:

1. The column names are not important
2. Both the number of items in that single column and the parameter can change

Any idea how to achieve this in pyspark? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some helper columns to pivot the dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x = 3

result = df.withColumn(
    'id',
    F.monotonically_increasing_id()
).withColumn(
    'id2',
    (F.col('id') / x).cast('int')
).withColumn(
    'id3',
    F.col('id') % x
).groupBy('id2').pivot('id3').agg(F.first('ColName')).orderBy('id2').drop('id2')

result.show()
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
|  d|  e|  f|
|  g|  h|  i|
|  j|  k|  l|
+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Would that work given the value of "x" is parameterized and can change based on who is calling that code?

Comment: yes, you can try changing the value of x and it should still work as long as its value is sensible

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `collect_list` and `row_number` to achieve this.

**Step 1:** Generate a custom row_number.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import floor, row_number, collect_list
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

no_of_columns = 3

df2 = df.withColumn("row_num", floor((row_number().over(Window.orderBy("ColName"))-1)/no_of_columns))
```

**Step 2:** Group the data using this row_number and use `collect_list` to create a list.

```
df3 = df2.groupBy("row_num").agg(collect_list("ColName").alias("col_list"))
```

**Step 3:** Use python's list comprehension to select all the elements from this list.

```
df3.select(*[df3.col_list[i].alias(f"col{i+1}") for i in range(no_of_columns)]).show()
```

**Output:**

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|   f|
|   g|   h|   i|
|   j|   k|   l|
+----+----+----+
```

Note: The parameter `no_of_columns` can be changed based on the required number of output columns.